# Does Windows Explorer do a bitwise copy of a hard drive

Tags: windows-explorer

I see a question asked previously under the heading "deleted files and their traces" which seems to cover part of my query. Prior to answering can you please confirm the answers given in that post as it probably explains it a lot better than I can. My specific queries which adds to that original question is:

1. If I am in Windows Explorer (Windows Vista), and I right click on the C drive & go copy & paste the entire c drive to an external hard drive & then transfer from there to another computer hard drive does the free space (i.e. previously deleted files) get copied over along with the files in use? I'm not concerned about whether the operating system files work when transferred or not; just the query regarding the transfer of deleted files.
2. Can you do a bitwise copy (i.e. exactly replicating every single bit from one disk to another) with windows explorer through right click on cdrive & copy & pasting it in full to another drive? (I find it hard to see in the "deleted files and their traces" if windows explorer can do a bitwise copy or not).
3. Similarly in the "deleted files and their traces" question it states: "Hardware cloning is usually a sector to sector copy, moving over everything to be the exact same (including partition sizes). Again does copy & pasting the entire c drive from windows explorer to an external hard drive constitute hardware cloning & again does the free space get copied in that instance?
4. Is there any difference if only part of the c drive is copied & pasted from windows explorer in terms of deleted files / free spaced being copied over? It appears from the "deleted files and their traces" question that it isn't copied in this instance?
5. Is there any article from windows or elsewhere which explains this further?

Comment: Please include a link to the question you reference.

Comment: I'm also not sure if this is a security question. This appears to be a general Windows file system question. There might be a tangent that touches security, but this does not appear to be a security question in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer is file-based, not byte-based. For example, if you were to copy the C:\ drive to another HDD, the newly-created files would be in completely different relative locations on the new HDD from each other and have different internal link structures. *Some system files would not get copied at all, nor would the boot sectors and UEFI data.*

Though copying files is useful for backup or for other purposes, the only effective way to image a disk is with software that operates at a lower level, below the file system, such as [DriveImage XML](https://www.runtime.org/dixml.htm) or [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx). Such imaging software can be used to make, among other things,

- An *exact* duplicate of a disk, including sectors with random information left after deleting files (which might contain hidden data),
- An image of all sectors shown by the file system (e.g. NTFS, FAT32) to be in use,
- An incremental copy of any changes to the disk since the last backup.